# SSH ignore global config

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I want SSH to ignore the global configuration file in a shared user environment where I do not have control over system-wide configuration since there are settings which conflict with my expected use of SSH (it sets defaults that are different from standard defaults)

As noted in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```
Configuration data is parsed as follows:
1. command line options
2. user-specific file
3. system-wide file
```

I want it to ignore that #3 exists.

I know that the `-F` flag can be used to specify per-user configuration file and ignore the system-wide file.

Another possible solution would be to override every possible parameter to the standard default in the user-specific file.  This is undesirable since the configuration may change as ssh is updated.

Ideally there would be a configuration directive like to stop processing options or to ignore the global file.

Is there a better way of ignoring the system-wide file without having to specify `-F ~/.ssh/config` every time?

Comment: `alias ssh='ssh -F ~/.ssh/config'`?

Comment: @DavidPostill That almost seems too simple... Don't know why I didn't think of that. You should consider putting that as an answer.

Comment: Does #1 override #3 or the other way around?

Comment: The first place (1 then 2 then 3) a setting is defined takes precedence.  So if `Option` is defined in the command line option, `Option` in `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` will be ignored.

Comment: An alias isn't a good general solution since various command-line commands access ssh config (one example is git).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I want SSH to ignore the global configuration file

> Is there a better way of ignoring the system-wide file without having to specify `-F ~/.ssh/config` every time?"

Use the following `alias`:

```
alias ssh='ssh -F ~/.ssh/config'
```

Comment: but isn't the `~/.ssh/config` global file and you are including it this way?

Comment: @IvanAracki `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is the system global file.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `-F none` to simply avoid reading any configuration files.

If you want to make it an alias:

```
alias ssh='ssh -F none'
```

Answer (score 0):

If an alias is awkward to use in a particular situation, you could create this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec ssh -F ~/.ssh/config "$@"
```

Call it `myssh` or whatever you like, make it executable, then run it like ssh:

```
myssh user@host ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could (temporarily) remove read permissions from the global config file you want to be ignored. Aliasing the `ssh` command (as suggested in some other answers) isn't a great solution because ssh config is used by various commands other than `ssh` itself, e.g. `git`.